# Craft storage dir as linked in capistrano

Tags: deployment

I'm having some issues with my install of craft on a staging server.

I'm deploying using Capistrano, and (perhaps wrongly) added craft/storage to linked_dirs (to share between deployments). Since doing that, things have not been going so well with my installation. I keep get "No response" screen in the browser, `(Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)`. I also get "unknown error occurred" messages when browsing round the admin doing normal things like updating entries etc.

The only consistent error is this one:

```
2015/03/26 17:33:53 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /var/www/50th/releases/20150326171328/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:916
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/50th/releases/20150326171328/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(230): Craft\WebApp->_enforceSystemStatusPermissions()
#1 /var/www/50th/releases/20150326171328/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#2 /var/www/50th/releases/20150326171328/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#3 /var/www/50th/releases/20150326171328/public/index.php(19): require_once('/var/www/50th/r...')
#4 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/
---
2015/03/26 17:33:53 [error] [application]
```

It's worth noting that the site is in offline-mode.

Any ideas?!

**Update:**
I've found a consistent error message when trying to access "/admin/users":
[DOMAINNAME...]/index.php/admin/actions/elementIndex/getElements net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Is being returned by jQuery trying to access elements. Does this help at all?

Comment: I've got 0 experience with Capistrano, so I can only offer some general advice. `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` is just Chome's way of saying "I expected to get a response, but I got nothing back". Usually some fatal error occurring on the server side.  Re: "unknown error occurred" - If you look i your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder for `[error]`, then you can find the underlying error message. Also worth checking for a `phperrors.log` file in that same folder.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not logging an error every time the "Unknown Error Occured" red box notification appears in the dashboard. It seems to be something problematic relating to `/admin/actions/elementIndex/getElements` - Issues mainly occurring on the index pages for entries. I think it's some sort of linux/server permissions issue, posibly to do with the storage folder...

Comment: @BradBell How would you go about deploying craft then? I'm having a lot of issues with Craft amd capistrano,. I keep getting ERROR_EMPTY_REPONSE on the front end, and lots via jQuery on the backend too. Do you hve any ideas what might be causing this? Craft can read write to storage directory. I don't understand what's going on!

Comment: Look at the call to getElements in your browser's console's Network tab. What's the response coming back from that request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've eventually tracked down this peculiar `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` to a php error buried deep in my apache logs - `zend_mm_heap corrupted`. So as it turns out nothing to do with Capistrano (or Craft) at all! This `zend_mm_heap` error is a php memory error that I seem to have solved by upgrading my version of PHP after unsuccessfully upping my `output_buffer` as suggested in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247977/what-does-zend-mm-heap-corrupted-mean). It's worth noting that there was nothing in the Craft log about this error, no mention of anything untoward. The `Craft\HttpException` I found above is, I believe, essentially a '404' error as my site was running in 'offline mode' so requests had to be run through `_enforceSystemStatusPermissions`.

I did initially have some issues with permissions with Capistrano where my server was setting new files created by craft to 644 www-data:www-data and therefore my user couldn't edit these files, despite being in the www-data group, and so Capistrano was having a hard time removing old releases. I've fixed this by adding a umask 002 to /etc/apache2/envvar.

Now that the `zend_mm_heap` error seems to be behaving, and my permissions are correct, deploying with Capistrano is working rather well. For future reference, my linked dirs config looks like this:

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{public/resources craft/config/local craft/storage}
```

`public/resources` is my (single) craft asset source, `craft/config/local` are my server-specific config files as suggested [here](https://github.com/BarrelStrength/Craft-Multi-Environment-Config) which is working nicely for me. `craft/storage` is obviously the craft storage folder that is shared between releases.

In terms of deployment, I think Capistrano (and other tools of a similar ilk) is great. I'm hosting my repository in a private BitBucket account and push new changes onto the master branch. I have two stages set up :production and :staging which deploy to two different vhosts on my server (staging domain is test.domain.com).

My stage configuration looks like this (for staging)

```
set :stage, :staging

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/domain-test"

# Allow user to define which branch to push, e.g.
# BRANCH=my-new-feature cap staging deploy
set :branch, ENV['BRANCH'] || "staging"
```

This last line is really helpful if I want to quickly test something on the master branch without having to merge it into the staging branch and push and deploy.

I hope that helps someone who comes across a similar issue. If anyone wants more info about my Capistrano set up, let me know. I highly recommend it as a method of deployment, once you figure out your (inevitable and strange) server errors!